# Writing non-text files using Python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, encryption, encoding

I am currently working on an encryption program and am faced with the problem of writing non-text files with Python 3.

For example, this will work (fEncode() is defined):

```
text = ''
textFile = open(textFileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for textLine in textFile:
    text += textLine
textFile.close()   

ciphertext = text
numPassCounter = 0
for password in passwords:
    ciphertext = fEncode(ciphertext, password, num_passwords[numPassCounter])
    numPassCounter += 1       

os.system("copy /y " + textFileName + " " + ciphertextFileName)
ciphertextFile = open(ciphertextFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
ciphertextFile.write(ciphertext)
ciphertextFile.close()
```

Here textFileName = 'C:\aRandomTextFile.txt'. However, if I replace it wil something like 'C:\aRandomImage.png' and replace

```
 ciphertextFile = open(textFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

with

```
 ciphertextFile = open(textFileName, 'wb')
```

and then try

```
 ciphertextFile.write(bytes(str(ciphertext, encoding='utf-8')))
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Comp_Sci/Coding/chr_ord_5.py", line 466, in <module>
ciphertextFile.write(bytes(str(ciphertext, encoding='utf-8')))
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `str.encode(ciphertext, encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you make your bytes string.  Consider the following, similar to what you're doing:

```
>>> bytes('banana')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes('banana')
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

or

```
>>> bytes(str('banana',encoding='utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes(str('banana',encoding='utf-8'))
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

But now try another way:

```
>>> bytes('banana'.encode('utf-8'))  # redundant, see last example
b'banana'
```

or

```
>>> bytes(ord(c) for c in 'banana')
b'banana'
```

or even just:

```
>>> 'banana'.encode()
b'banana'
```

So now you can see that `bytes(str('banana',encoding='utf-8'))` is taking a string, making it a binary string, casting it as an unencoded string, and then trying to make a bytes string out of it again.

Hope that helps.